# Remove everything to the right of the ampersand with RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble removing the ampersand and everything to the right of it in this

> 5HnVGGOrMyw&1394058973

I can't figure out how to do this with RegEx, and rtrim() is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `substr` and `strrpos`?

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, '&'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = preg_replace('/([^&]*)&.*/', "$1", $in);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace("/([^&]+)(.+)/", '$1', '5HnVGGOrMyw&1394058973');
```